# ddply with multiple columns isn't working

Tags: r, plyr

The following code works:

```
tdata <- read.table(filename, header=T, colClasses=c(rep("character", 6), rep("numeric", 3)))
names(tdata) <- c("Date", "City", "Key", "Number", "Count")
indata <- transform(tdata, Date = as.Date(Date), Sum = Number*Count)
dd <- ddply(indata, .(paste(Key, substr(City,1,3), sep=","), summarize, total=sum(Sum))
```

and produces

```
1 KEY1,NEW 3456
```

but the following:

```
tdata <- read.table(filename, header=T, colClasses=c(rep("character", 6), rep("numeric", 3)))
names(tdata) <- c("Date", "City", "Key", "Number", "Count")
indata <- transform(tdata, Date = as.Date(Date), Sum = Number*Count)
dd <- ddply(indata, .(paste(Key, City, sep=","), summarize, total=sum(Sum))
```

produces

```
1 KEY1,NEW-YORK
1 3456
```

in two different rows, what is the special thing about adding the substr, is the "-" causing the problem of having two rows instead of one row?

Comment: are you sure it's not just a problem with your output width?  Since there is a 1 by each row, that indicates to me those actually belong to the same row, just printed on different lines.

Comment: what do you mean by the output width?  you mean this line tdata <- read.table(filename, header=T, colClasses=c(rep("character", 6), rep("numeric", 3))) @@

Comment: Perhaps someone else could, but I don't think I could guess what's wrong without a reproducible example.

Comment: @nevermind no I mean your R session option "width".  Try running options(width=138L) and then print out the result of your second call

Comment: where do I put the width option?

Comment: you can either run it in your console or put that line before all the code you have in the above question.  All it will do is change the number of characters (or columns) that are printed in the console on each line, before the console skips to the next line to continue printing.  Only need to run it once for a session

Comment: yay that did work!!!! put it in an answer so I can accept it